# Is it possible to include useful elisp and keyboard formatting help in the How to Format sidebar?

Tags: feature-request

I've seem people edit my posts and add **<kbd>** tags to my posts which is quite handy for showing key-sequences. Is it possible to customise the "How to Format" sidebar with these often handy formatting tips as well as list conventions for formatting function and variable references?

Comment: @Malabarba: no, there is a "How to Format" sidebar that appears when you change focus to the question text box.

Comment: you're right, my mistake.

Comment: As for the question itself. I like the general idea, but we've already settled on not using kbd tags. See http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/q/15/50. So if somebody tried to do that to your post, it should have been rejected. :-)